# MSDN Subscriber Benefits - Visual Studio Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2017, msdn

I need to test some software bespoke software out, which I have created, for a client.

I need to make sure that it works on Server 2016 Data Center.

I am happy to subscribe to the Visual Studio Subscription Pro as I notice it has access to Server 2016 as part of the subscriber benefits.

The Software benefits page lists only "Windows Server 2016", So I need to make sure that, as part of that install, I can get my mittens on Data Center 2016.

Secondly, if Data Center 2016 is indeed available, then I need to be able to ensure that all cores are "unlocked" for use. So I think 16 cores is what it is licensed at when you purchase a full license, and then you purchase additional core packs depending on the server. However, If I'm testing, I need to know that it does the job, and need access to ALL cores on the server.

Sorry about the long winded explanation, but it boils down to the following:

1) Does the Visual Studio Pro Subscription give me access to Server 2016 Data Center edition?

2) Does this give me access to all cores on the machine?

3) Is the license key provided perpetual?. I need to know my lab rig just won't "shut off"/deactivate/become a brick

NB - I contacted Microsoft and was shuffled around to about 8 different people, from pre-sales, tech support, professional support, none of whom could answer my question.

Cheers,

Chud

Comment: you can try the vs community as well

Comment: Neville, I need access to server 2016 Data Center. Server 2016 is part of the visual studio Subscriber benefits, amongst other eligible software. My question relates to the benefits attached to the subscriptions, not visual studio itself. Thanks.

Comment: Well since they are the actual benefits to the vs subscription, you have a better chance of finding someone who has subscribed there

Comment: Neville, Apologies. I took your initial response not as "try the vs community" but as "try vs community" IE - the free version of VS. sorry sorry